# Is there any way to "only" overwrite the specific key-value in a json file

Tags: python, list, dictionary, file

I have a `myfile.txt` like a list of dictionaries in python as follows :

```
[{"jp": "str1", "jp_ch": "str1_output"}, {"jp": "str2", "jp_ch": "str2_output"}]
```

I want to modify a specific value within the dictionary in the list

For example I want to change `"jp_ch": "str1_output"` to `"jp_ch": "new_string"`

My naive approach is as follows

(1.) open `myfile.txt` and `json.loads()` as `jsf #variable-name`

(2.) modify a specific value in the `jsf`

(3.) then overwrite the "whole" `myfile.txt` with `jsf`

```
def edit(to_correct, corrected):
    file_name = 'myfile.txt'
    f = open(file_name, 'r')
    jsf = json.loads(f.read())
    for seg in jsf:
        for property in seg:
            if(str(seg[property])==to_correct):
                sure = input("Are you sure this is the correct one (* / n) : ")
                if(sure != 'n'):
                    seg[property]=corrected
                return

    #then I overwrite the whole myfile.txt with jsf.

            
to_correct = input("what is the one to-correct : ")
corrected = input("what is the corrected answer for that : ")
edit(to_correct, corrected)
```

Is there any way to only overwrite the specific value in the `myfile.txt` instead of overwriting the whole `myfile.txt`

For example :

```
[{"jp": "str1", "jp_ch": "str1_output"}, {"jp": "str2", "jp_ch": "str2_output"}]
```

If I want to change `"jp_ch": "str1_output"` to `"jp_ch": "new_string"`, I hope to simply replace the former with the latter rather than overwrite the whole `myfile.txt`.

Comment: The short version is, there are wrappers, but it still has to read and process the entire file. That is nothing to do with Python; it's a consequence of **how files work**. Please see the linked duplicate for details.